# Add Style on subclass with css or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish I could add a style to all the classes below the first div,
So when I move the mouse over

all classes must stylize in this way:

```
background-color:black !important;
color:white !important;
```

[I can't make all the white writing with css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzfig.png)

```html
<div data-id="#hMS2r-2141" class="event-item-wrapper ">
<article itemscope=""
    class="event-list post-2141 simple_event type-simple_event status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry simple_event_category-eventi">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <div class="date-info">
                <span class="date-month">May</span>
                <span class="date-day-year">11, 2018</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <div class="info-event">
                <h3 class="entry-title">Corso Acquarello</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
                nonummy ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Exolon

Try this code it works:

```css
#MouseHover:hover{
background-color:black !important;
color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="#hMS2r-2141" class="event-item-wrapper" id="MouseHover">
<article itemscope=""
    class="event-list post-2141 simple_event type-simple_event status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry simple_event_category-eventi">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left media-middle">
            <div class="date-info">
                <span class="date-month">May</span>
                <span class="date-day-year">11, 2018</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <div class="info-event">
                <h3 class="entry-title">Corso Acquarello</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="entry-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
                nonummy ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To apply the styles to any child and subchild of the wrapper on hover do

```
.event-item-wrapper:hover * {
  background-color:black !important;
  color:white !important;
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5sjmwbqf/).

To apply the styles to specific children of the wrapper on hover, you need to list the specific classes like this

```
.event-item-wrapper:hover .event-list,
.event-item-wrapper:hover .media,
.event-item-wrapper:hover .media-left,
.event-item-wrapper:hover .date-info,
.event-item-wrapper:hover .date-month {
  background-color:black !important;
  color:white !important;
}
```

Comment: 2nd piece of code can be simplified a bit:  .event-item-wrapper:hover :is(.event-list, .media, .media-left, .date-info, .date-month)

Answer (score 1):

```
Using Jquery and css :

Jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".event-item-wrapper").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("Mydivadd");
    });
});

Css:
<style>
.Mydivadd {
  background-color:red !important;
  color:white !important;
}
</style>
```